# Show UITableView footer when empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that is sometimes empty, and I have a footer for that `UITableView`. What I want is the footer to always appear, even when there is no content in the table view. Is this possible? Or is it better to just add an extra cell to the `UITableView` and use that as the footer?

Would prefer to keep it separate as a footer instead of just adding it to the end of the `UITableView` as a cell.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok First thing is, as you said "UITableView that is sometimes empty". So if your table is empty and you add a footer view in it. Like below

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView* myFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [myFooterView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    return myFooterView;
}
```

Your footer view will display on top of the tableview as there is no row in tableview.something like in below image. Red is TableView color and Blue is footer view color.

[image]

And when your table is not empty footer view will be like

[image]

So i suggest you to add and extra view below table view and display content in that view. Hope this will clear your doubts enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this when there are no rows

```
UIView* footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
    [footerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:(UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone)];
    [self.tableView setContentInset:(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -350, 0))];
```

Comment: I think this is too hackey, don't like the idea of editing the content insets at all

Comment: It wont create any problem

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call the table view functions that have the heightForFooterInSection and viewForFooterInSection as parameters. In the first one you return the height you want for the footer and in the second one, you return the view that you want to be shown as the footer view. For example:

```
   import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var numberOfCells = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ExampleCellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExampleCellTableViewCell")

    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfCells
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExampleCellTableViewCell") as? ExampleCellTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 80.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return FooterView.instanceFromNib()
    }
}
```

Even if the number of cells is 0, the footer view will appear:
[image: TabelView with the number of cells equal 0 and a footer view]

You can check the full example project here: 
https://github.com/erichflock/TableViewWithFooter

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to have a standard footer with empty/no text (basically just an empty space) - you can set a space " " as your footer text. This way the footer will be displayed and your footer height will take effect.